# Java - Reading in value from text

Tags: java, parsing

OK so I have read plenty of examples on here dealing with reading in lines from a text file and splitting them up but im not quite sure I understand how to do it in my situation.  I have a file that is basically separated into three columns as follows:

```
         START  5000
         FIND   A
         PLUS   B
         SAVE   C
         STOP   
 A,      INT    69
 B,      INT    -420
 C,      CRAZY  008484342
```

What I am trying to do is read in this .txt file containing the above information. I figured reading in the file line by line would be best, then splitting it into the correct columns. The problem that I am having is the fact that the 1st column is not always here. It is an optional one.  If they were all filled in, im almost positive I could just use use something like

```
 String[] array1 = myLine.split(",");
```

Another idea I had was to split the line based on ,'s  then split the line again based on " " but im not exactly sure how to do this.  Maybe somthing like

```
 String[] array1 = myLine.split(",");
 String[] array2 = array1[1].split(" ");
```

Also, is there any way to just read in the file and store each row into like (String,  String String) then just check for ints vs strings?  Maybe in a try catch? or like:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(File);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String str = input.next();
            try{
                b = Integer.parseInt(str);
             }
```

I am not sure if this is as hard as a task as im making it but maybe so... Any help with this topic would be appreciated.

After looking over some more code, I have the following to start:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {

    String file ="TEST.txt";

        try{

            FileReader input = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(input);

            String line;

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {


                // Is this where I would attempt to split the lines?
                System.out.println(line);

            }

            bufferReader.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());                      
        }
     }

 }
```

So with this, I am successfully reading in the file and displaying the information back to the output console.  Now for separating the lines...  Ill be posting my work as I go, any help and or suggestions would be appreciated!  Also thank you to those who have already commented with helping to split the stings, ill be attempting this now!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both expressions and only checked the array's length. e.g.:

```
String[] array = line.trim().split("[, ]+");
switch(array.length) {
    case 2: 
        // do something
        break;
    case 3: 
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // something wrong
        break;
}
```

The `trim()` in the line is for avoid empty string in the first element array.

Comment: If I did it like this, wouldnt the line with STOP only be length 1?

Comment: If you are using scanner, there is not more lines. If you have an empty line in the end, you can stop on `if (line == null || line.trim().isEmpty()) { /* stop */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(" +")` which will split on any numbers of spaces. This works because `split` handles regex. If you want to split on any type of whitespace you can also use `split("\\s+)`. After you get the array check if it has 2 or 3 elements and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Add another quote mark to end the string in your 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I don't have the time yet for a long answer. But I'd recommend you to read a little bit about regular expressions (RegEx) and how it is used in java ... I am sure this will help you with this problem and a huge amount of future problems like this ...

Try this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html ... of this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ ... if the first one does not help ;)